# Wix Custom Action result not saved to file

Tags: c#, wix

I have created a C# application that uses a SQL Server database, or a local SQLite database. To synchronize the two I created a command line converter (also C#) that creates the SQLite file from the SQL Server database.
All works well, and in the Wix installer I do not include the SQLite database file. This saves space and is more secure as the database contains pricing information (the SQL Server is not visible outside our company network). In the installer I created a custom action to run the converter (XML simplified for clarity).

```
<CustomAction Id="SQLConvert"
              FileKey="SqlConverter.exe"
              ExeCommand="-sqlitefile:[INSTALLDIR]Database.db3"
              Execute="commit"
              Impersonate="yes"
              Return="ignore" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="SQLConvert" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT REMOVE ~= "ALL"</Custom>
    <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallFinalize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

This will start the converter (it does not run hidden) but the resulting file (or the log) are nowhere to be found. Where was the file saved? It should have been saved in the install directory. The converter gets this information through the ExeCommand option.